# Get the user who reacted discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    #the embedded msg that was sent        
    global msg 
    message_id1 = payload.message_id 
    #checks if the message that was sent is the message the reaction was added to
    if message_id1 == msg.id:
      ..code..
```

I also told the bot to add reactions (all the reactions from 1 to 9) to the message but when I said:

```
if payload.emoji.name == '1️⃣':
   ..code..
```

it did whatever the code said after that but I want it to ignore the bot's reaction and just take user reaction and later on I want it to only use 2 user's reactions (the ones who called the function).

Is there some kind of syntax that checks the id or username of the people who reacted so I can add it to the if statement at the start?

Answer (score 0):

The payload is the type: RawReactionActionEvent, which has the attributes of member. You can do,

```
if payload.member.id == bot.user.id:
   return
```